# Storing selective elements in GPU global memory

Tags: c#, cuda, parallel-processing, cudafy.net

We are doing comparisons on the GPU using CUDAfy.NET. For that we are passing two arrays, one of which contains the data and the other stores the results.
I only want to store those elements in the result array which satisfy a certain condition. But the array ends up with unwanted entries where condition doesn't satisfy.
How can I filter these unwanted entries from the results array and return the filtered array back to the main function?

```
[Cudafy]
public static void Comparisons(GThread thread, int[] a,int[] c, int iter)
{
    int tx = thread.threadIdx.x;
    if(tx < iter)
    {
        if(a[tx] < tolerance)  //tolerance is some user defined number
        {
            c[tx] = a[tx];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do this in multiple kernel passes.

Example:
a = [1,2,1,2,1,2]
tolerance = 2

First pass:
Create an array that contains 1 for "keep element" or 0 for "discard element"
p = [1,0,1,0,1,0]

Second pass:
Perform a parallel prefix sum on the p array.
i = [0,1,1,2,2,3]
(There are lots of whitepapers on this topic)

Third pass:
Use a,p, and i.
One thread per element.
if p[threadIdx.x] equals 1 then put a[threadIdx.x] in c[i[threadIdx.x]]
(You could use shared memory here to coalesce the writing to c array better)

The result array c will contain [1,1,1]